# System throws exception during on click on the navigate Button in Xamarin.Forms App

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

On click on the navigate button, system throws exception in my xamarin.Form app. I am trying to get the `email` text value and display in the `Home` page.

```cs
Exception: Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: 
<Timeout exceeded getting exception details>`
```

MainPage.xaml.cs;

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var emailText = emailEntry.Text;
        var passwordText = passwordEntry.Text;
    }
    int count = 0;

    public void Button_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string text = emailEntry.Text;
    }

    public async void NavigateButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Home(emailEntry.Text));
    }
}
```

Following is my `Home.xaml.cs` where I need to display the text email value from the MainPage.xaml.cs;

```cs
public partial class Home : ContentPage
{
    public Home(string parameter1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        HomeLabel.Text = parameter1;
    }
}
```

App.xaml.cs details below;

```cs
public partial class App : Application
{
    string parameter1;
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var tabbedPage = new TabbedPage();
        tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Home(parameter1));
        tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Map());
        tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Settings());
        MainPage = new MainPage();
        //MainPage = new TabbedPage();
        //MainPage = tabbedPage;
    }

    protected override void OnStart()
    {
        // Handle when your app starts
    }

    protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        // Handle when your app resumes
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:soccerapp"
    x:Class="soccerapp.MainPage">

    <StackLayout Spacing="20" Padding="50">
        <Entry x:Name="emailEntry" Placeholder="Email Id"></Entry>
        <Entry x:Name="passwordEntry" Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True"></Entry>
        <Button Text="Log In"  Clicked="Button_Clicked" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="#404751"></Button>
        <Button Text="Navigate to Home"  Clicked="NavigateButton_OnClicked" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="ForestGreen"></Button>

        <!-- Place new controls here -->
        <Label Text="Welcome Mate!" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Home.xaml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="soccerapp.Home" BackgroundColor="GreenYellow" Title="Home">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label x:Name="HomeLabel"  Text="Home Page is here" TextColor="White"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Can you post your xaml

Comment: InvalidOperationException seems weird here.  Can you check the stack trace to see the source of the exception?

Comment: Why do you use `Navigation.PushAsync(new Home(...))` if you already have this page in your `TabbedPage`?

Comment: he's not actually using that TabbedPage.  But that brings up a good point, he is trying to use Navigation when he doesn't have a NavigationPage

Comment: MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());

Comment: If I use `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());` I am navigated to Home successfully and the text value displayed, but in this case, I am unable to see other Tabs like `Map, Settings`

Comment: @soccerway please see my answer, you use `Navigation` and `TabbedPage` in a wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, first of all you have to create `NavigationPage` in you App.xaml.cs. Also, you need to move your `TabbedPage` initialization into separate `xaml` file or in `NavigationsClicked` event.

1. Edit your App.xaml.cs:

```cs
public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    }
```

2. There are 2 ways of doing it:

Create your TabbedPage in `NavigationClicked` event:

```cs
public async void NavigateButton_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var tabbedPage = new TabbedPage();
    tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Home(parameter1));
    tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Map());
    tabbedPage.Children.Add(new Settings());
    await Navigation.PushAsync(tabbedPage);
}
```

or create new XAML file for `TabbedPage`:

```xml
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            x:Class="MyTabbedPage">
  <!--Pages can be added as references or inline-->
    <ContentPage Title="HomeTitle">
  <!--Content for Home Page-->
    </ContentPage>

    <ContentPage Title="MapTitle">
  <!--Content for Map Page-->
    </ContentPage>

    <ContentPage Title="SettingsTitle">
  <!--Content for Settings Page-->
    </ContentPage>
</TabbedPage>
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't get that completely, where do I need add `CurrentPage = Children[yourSpecificIndex];`

Comment: @soccerway hmm, by the way, I'm wrong. You didn't use your tabbed page in an app. I'll edit my answer now, please wait.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that, but what do you mean by `CurrentPage`, in my case it should be MainPage right ?

Comment: I am confused now, why shouldn't i use the tabbed page ? Where do i make changes now ?

Comment: @soccerway Yes, you should. You should use `TabbedPage`, but in a proper way. You initialize it in App.xaml.cs, but never use. Please see my answer edit.

Comment: Now I am able to pass the email text to Home Page as per advised, but unable to see all tabs while navigated to Home page

Comment: @soccerway provide a code snippet of what you have done.

Comment: Awesome, this is working now, will accept your answer

Comment: A small typo to correct here `await Navigation.PushAsync(tabbedPage());`, I think it should be `await Navigation.PushAsync(tabbedPage);`